# Ansible: run an interactive shell script locally just runs through

Tags: ansible

I have an interactive build shell script, which contains sections like this:

```
echo "Is this correct?"
select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
    case $yn in
        Yes ) break;;
        No ) exit;;
    esac
done
```

If I run the script on its own (`./runscript.sh`), then I get correctly prompted.

But if I run the shell script from inside ansible, like this:

```
  tasks:
    - name: Run script
      shell: "./runscript.sh {{param1}} {{param2}} {{param3}}"
      args:
          chdir: "../../path/to/script/"
      run_once: true
      delegate_to: localhost
```

Then this thing just runs through and I get no prompt, and I have no idea what's going on. Did it complete? How, with what settings? Does it just always implicitly assume a "YES"?

Comment: If you're interested in getting the prompts check the expect module: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/expect_module.html

Answer (score 1):

The shell module execution is failing. If you print the `rc` of the script execution it should be different from 0.
The reason is that the shell module
[runs the command through a shell (/bin/sh)](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html#synopsis), while `select` is a Bash construct.

Comment: Very interesting. Even if I have `#!/bin/bash` at the top of `runscript.sh`?

Comment: The `#!` is ignored since in this case the script is invoked in a shell. Try to run manually `/bin/sh runscript.sh` and you'll get an error. The ansible module runs the same command, hence the error. You can also handle the error by checking the rc in ansible and explicitly make the execution fail by using `failed_when`.